# jQuery .load browser cache overrides body class transitions

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, caching, css-transitions

My .load ajax function:

1) Click link

2) Loads requested page while animating a css transition (body add/remove class)

3) If page request loads quicker than 400ms it knows to wait before removing body class and revealing page

This works perfectly on my local dev environment. But when on live server the ajax page cache overrides the body class transition and snap loads the page on top, disregarding the timer as described above (3).

Fixes I've found are $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); which adds a string to the url so the browser thinks it's a unique page... UGLY.

What other work arounds are possible? I could wait the 400ms before loading each page, but that's slow and un-pro :)

Many thanks in advance.
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the fix...

In your .htaccess add:

```
<filesMatch "\.(html|php|js|css)$">
    FileETag None
    <ifModule mod_headers.c>
        Header unset ETag
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
    </ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

Forces apache cache to not store basic (listed) files.

*phew*